# How substr_count php function works?

Tags: php, logic

I want to count single character comes in a string but continuous way.

```
<?php 
echo $strin = "abcaaabbcccccdaasvvbbvvtteesgggg";
echo "</br>";
$str_l = strlen($strin);
$i  = $j = 0;
$temp_c = "";
for($i;$i<$str_l;$i++){
$j = 0;
$j = substr_count($strin, $strin[$i]);
 echo $strin[$i]." is repeated ".$j." times </br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this -

```
$string = "abcaaabbcccccdaasvvbbvvtteesgggg";
// Split string by character and convert to array
$temp = str_split($string);
// Count values present in array
array_count_values($temp);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [a] => 6 [b] => 5 [c] => 6 [d] => 1 [s] => 2 [v] => 4 [t] => 2 [e] => 2 [g] => 4 )
```

[array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

[str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

**For continuous occurrences**

```
// split and create array with unique characters
$new = array_unique(str_split($string));
$chars = [];
foreach($new as $c) {
   // regex check for character's multiple occurrences 
   preg_match_all("/($c)\\1+/", $string, $matches);
   // Store the count
   $chars[$c] = count($matches[0]);
}
print_r($chars);
```

**Outpur**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 1
    [d] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [v] => 2
    [t] => 1
    [e] => 1
    [g] => 1
)
```

Comment: but a comes 2 times in continuous way

Comment: YOu dont want the total occurrences?

Comment: You only want the continuous occurrence not single, right?

Comment: Yes continuous occurrence